# Regex to extract date from website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape content from a website like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import re

dat   = re.compile("Berlin, \d{2}. \w+\b \d{4}")
url   = 'https://www.alternativefuer.de/gauland-scheinbares-umdenken-der-altparteien-ist-blanker-opportunismus/'
r     = requests.get(url)
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data  = soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'content','role':'main'})

text  = data.findNext("div").text
```

Then I would like to extract the date which is contained in the beginning of the string. So I tried both

```
date  = data.findAll(text=re.compile("Berlin, \d{2}. \w+\b \d{4}"))
```

and

```
date  = dat.match(text)
```

If I copypaste the string to python regex does match the date. But here both options don't seem to work. Could anyone point me to where the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your webscraping is collecting the data correctly, the string you grab looks like `"Berlin, 30. November 2016."`, so...

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Berlin, 30. November 2016."
>>> res = re.search("(\d+).+?(\w+).+?(\d+)", string)
>>> res.group(1)
'30'
>>> res.group(2)
'November'
>>> res.group(3)
'2016'
```

- You just need to enclose the words/digits you want with `(` and `)` so you can grab the match group later. Or you can use `findall` but since there's only one match you want, it's overkill.
- If you don't want each individual group, simply use the same pattern using `res.group()` to get the entire match.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
dat   = re.compile("Berlin, \d{2}. \w+\b \d{4}")
```

to

```
dat   = re.compile("Berlin, \d{2}\. \w+ \d{4}")
```

escape the keyword `.` in the regex, and remove the `\b`, not need to use it.

change

```
date  = dat.match(text)
```

to

```
date  = dat.search(text)
```

`text` starts with `\nBerlin, 30. November 2016. Zum s....`, there is a new line at the beginning, and `match` will start at `\n`, change it to `search`